# How to Interleave two strings in Python when their lengths are not equal?

Tags: python, string

I know a way to interleave two strings using Python but it works only if their lengths are equal:

```
u = 'Abcd'
l = 'Wxyz'
res = "".join(i + j for i, j in zip(u, l))
print(res)
```

This will give me the correct Output:`AWbxcydz`
But if the strings are `u = 'Utkarsh'` and `l = 'Jain'`, the same method does not give the correct answer. Can someone suggest a way to do so?

Comment: Which output are you looking for with those strings?

Comment: The output in this case should be: 'UJtakianrsh' but my method gives the output as: 'UJtakian'

Comment: Don't arbitrarily tag **both** `python-3.x` and `python-2.7`. It doesn't add any information to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `zip_longest` from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

u = 'Abcdefgh'
l = 'Wxyz'
res = "".join(i + j for i, j in zip_longest(u, l, fillvalue=''))
print(res)
```

Comment: Note that since OP has unhelpfully tagged their question with both 2.7 and 3.x, in 2.7 this method is called `izip_longest`.

Comment: Thanks it works..:)